# How to allow the user to choose whether the continue the program or exit it (C#)

Tags: c#, loops, user-controls, user-input

I've written a fairly simple program that displays a menu of choices and performs calculations based on the user's input.  I'd like to make the program behave so that it asks the user if they would like to continue back to the menue or exit the program instead.  I'm thinking that it might require a loop of some kind, but I'm unsure as to how to implement it.

Here is my code

```
using System;

namespace WarmUpCalculations

{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Chemistry Formula Calculator!\n\n\n");

            Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for the Density Calculator");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 2 for the Moles Calculator");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 3 for the Energy of a Wave Calculator");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 4 for the Ideal Gas Law Calculator\n\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a Number from the Options above");
            string choice = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (choice)
            {
                case "1":
                    DensityCalculator();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    MolesCalculator();
                    break;
                case "3":
                    EnergyOfWaveCalculator();
                    break;
                case "4":
                    IdealGasLawCalculator();
                    break;
            }
        }

        static void DensityCalculator()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Density Calaculator\n\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Will this be for Grams or Kilograms?");
            Console.WriteLine("Type 'g' for Grams or 'kg' for Kilograms");
            string unitMass = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your Mass");
            Decimal Mass = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter units for Volume");
            string unitVolume = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your Volume");
            Decimal Volume = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
            Decimal Density = Mass / Volume;
            Math.Round(Density, 4);
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Moles Calaculator\n\n");
            Console.Write("Your Density is ");
            Console.Write(Density);
            Console.Write(unitMass);
            Console.Write("/");
            Console.WriteLine(unitVolume);
            Console.Write(" \n\n");

        }

        static void MolesCalculator()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Moles Calaculator\n\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter mass of sample");
            Decimal Mass = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your molar mass");
            Decimal MolarMass = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
            Decimal Moles = Mass / MolarMass;
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Moles Calaculator\n\n");
            Console.Write("Your sample has ");
            Console.Write(Moles);
            Console.Write(" moles\n\n");

        }

        static void EnergyOfWaveCalculator()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Energy of Wave Calaculator\n\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the frequency");
            double Frequency = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            double PlancksConstant = 6.626e-34;
            double Energy = PlancksConstant * Frequency;
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Energy of Wave Calaculator\n\n");
            Console.Write("The answer is ");
            Console.Write(Energy);
            Console.Write(" \n\n");

        }

        static void IdealGasLawCalculator()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Ideal Gas Law Calaculator\n\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to solve the following equation for Pressure or Volume?  Press v for Volume or p for Pressure");
            string Frequency = Console.ReadLine();

            if (Frequency == "v"){
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Ideal Gas Law Calaculator\n\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the pressure");
                decimal Pressure = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the the number of moles");
                decimal NumberOfMoles = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the the temperature in degrees Kelvin");
                decimal TemperatureKelvin = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
                decimal GasLawConstant = Convert.ToDecimal(8.314);
                decimal IdealGasLaw = NumberOfMoles * GasLawConstant * TemperatureKelvin / Pressure;
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Energy of Wave Calaculator\n\n");
                Console.Write("Your answer is ");
                Console.Write(IdealGasLaw);
                Console.Write(" \n\n");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Ideal Gas Law Calaculator\n\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the volume");
                decimal Volume = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the the number of moles");
                decimal NumberOfMoles = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the the temperature in degrees Kelvin");
                decimal TemperatureKelvin = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
                decimal GasLawConstant = Convert.ToDecimal(8.314);
                decimal IdealGasLaw = NumberOfMoles * GasLawConstant * TemperatureKelvin / Volume;
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Energy of Wave Calaculator\n\n");
                Console.Write("Your answer is ");
                Console.Write(IdealGasLaw);
                Console.Write(" \n\n");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you want the users to have the choice?

Comment: That's a good question Mikael, I'm not exactly sure where.  I they finish their calculation from their initial choice, I would like the program to ask if they would like to return to the menu

Comment: Ok, I think the best would to make a new method for the calculation menu, and execute it straight from the main method, and reuse a call to that method as a choice in the end of the calculations. Check the answer

Comment: I've gotten the help I needed, but thanks for your input as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward. You had the right idea.

```
bool shouldContinue = true;
while(shouldContinue){
        Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for the Density Calculator");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 2 for the Moles Calculator");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 3 for the Energy of a Wave Calculator");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 4 for the Ideal Gas Law Calculator\n\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 5 to exit");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a Number from the Options above");
        string choice = Console.ReadLine();

        switch (choice)
        {
            case "1":
                DensityCalculator();
                break;
            case "2":
                MolesCalculator();
                break;
            case "3":
                EnergyOfWaveCalculator();
                break;
            case "4":
                IdealGasLawCalculator();
                break;
            case "5":
            shouldContinue = false;
                break;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same logic as for calculator choice and put all your code inside loop.

Change your code in `Main`:

```
char action = 'Y';      //create varible for user choice (continue or not)
while (action == 'Y')   // add loop
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Chemistry Formula Calculator!\n\n\n");

    Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for the Density Calculator");
    Console.WriteLine("Press 2 for the Moles Calculator");
    Console.WriteLine("Press 3 for the Energy of a Wave Calculator");
    Console.WriteLine("Press 4 for the Ideal Gas Law Calculator\n\n");
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a Number from the Options above");
    string choice = Console.ReadLine();

    switch (choice)
    {
        case "1":
            DensityCalculator();
            break;
        case "2":
            MolesCalculator();
            break;
        case "3":
            EnergyOfWaveCalculator();
            break;
        case "4":
            IdealGasLawCalculator();
            break;
    }

    //add these lines
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue!\n\n\n");        
    Console.WriteLine("Press Y to continue");
    Console.WriteLine("Press N to finish");    
    action = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
}
```

Or better option is:

Put all code from `Main` inside some method(i.e. `Start()`) and then in `Main`:

```
char action = 'Y';
while (action == 'Y')
{
    Start();

    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue!\n\n\n");        
    Console.WriteLine("Press Y to continue");
    Console.WriteLine("Press N to finish");    
    action = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new method `Menu`

Put the menu code in there and then just call upon it when you need it. At the end of `Main()` you can use a simple if case

```
Console.WriteLine("Type 'exit' to quit");
if(Console.ReadLine() == "exit") 
{

}else 
{
    Menu();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this.. there is too much code in the main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ChooseCalculationMenu();
}

public void ChooseCalculationMenu()
{
    // Put the code from Main here instead
}
```

and in the end of each calculation method:

```
Console.WriteLine("Press c to continue or q to quit.");
if (Console.Readline() == "q"); 
{}
else 
{
    ChooseCalculationMenu();
}
```